# readTimeout exception while http service invoker is used

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, serversocket, httpinvoker

I am new to spring boot.

I am getting this exception: COULD NOT ACCESS HTTP INVOKER REMOTE SERVICE AT [service URL]; nested exception is Java.net.SocketTimeOutException: Read Time out.

I need a solution for this. I went into the XML file to increase the readTimeout while that service URL is called but it says no such property
There is a bean defined for that property

I tried increasing server and client timeout but no luck.

Comment: <bean id="<service URL> " class="<package name>HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean">
   <property name="serviceUrl" value=""/>
   <property name="serviceInterface" value="<package_name> "/>
   <property name="httpInvokerRequestExecutor" ref="httpReqExecutor"/>

Answer (score 0):

**Increase the read timeout for httpInvokerRequestExecuter OR you can set it to 0**

```
<bean id="httpInvokerReqExecutor" class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.CommonsHttpInvokerRequestExecuto‌​r" > 
     <property name="readTimeout" value="0" /> 
</bean>
```

**Try this once.**

Comment: I appreciate your help. But it is not working. I added this line into the .XML file right after I have defined bean which I mentioned in the comment of the questio

Comment: Please check once bean id and ref are the same or not.

Comment: Bean I'd - is the service URL that client will use and ref is httpReqExecutor

Comment: Above of all the class next to the bean I'd is created by user which is extending HttpinvokerProxyfactorybean

Comment: yeah, I got it. I am telling about this `id="httpInvokerReqExecutor"` and `ref="httpReqExecutor"`